# Cascade update with selectbox inside editor form with DevExtreme

Tags: devextreme

I'm using a `DevExtreme` for `CRUD` operations on a table.

I'm using the `Form` editing mode, which has inside two `SelectBox` items:

```
items.AddSimpleFor(m => m.Score).Editor(editor => editor.SelectBox().DataSource(entityTypes).DisplayExpr("Name").ValueExpr("Score"));
items.AddSimpleFor(m => m.CreatorId).Editor(editor => editor.SelectBox());
```

I need to update the values inside the second `SelectBox` according to the selected value in the first one.

In "normal `HTML`" I was able to get references to those elements and set the callbacks accordingly, but now, inside the `configurator` definition for the `form`, I can't.

How do I get those references? Setting the `Name` property for the `SelectBox` did not work...

Answer (score 0):

DevExtreme does not allow to easily reference other form's items or even the parent form. You can use jQuery's [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest) method to get the parent form's element and then [getEditor](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxForm/Methods/#getEditordataField) to get the second select box.

```
        .Editor(editor => editor.SelectBox().DataSource(entityTypes).DisplayExpr("Name").ValueExpr("Score")
        .OnSelectionChanged(
            @<text>
                function({element, selectedItem}) {
                    const form = element.closest(".dx-form").dxForm("instance")

                    // get the second select box instance by name
                    const creatorSelectBox = form.getEditor("CreatorId")
                    // selectedItem.Score here holds the value of the first select box
                }
             </text>));
```